# CMake's execute_process doesn't set any of variables

Tags: cmake

I have some problem with cmake's `execute_process` command. I've used different combinations (positive with correct commands, with `echo` and negative, with unexisting commands), but  `OUTPUT_VARIABLE`, `ERROR_VARIABLE` and `RESULT_VARIABLE` are always empty:

```
set(__BUILD_VERSION "sss")
set(__ERROR_VARIABLE "aaa")
set(__EXECUTE_RESULT 0)

execute_process(
    COMMAND wrong_command
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE __BUILD_VERSION
    ERROR_VARIABLE  __ERROR_VARIABLE
    RESULT_VARIABLE __EXECUTE_RESULT
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

message( STATUS "ERROR: ${__ERROR_VARIABLE}" )
message( STATUS "OUTPUT_VARIABLE: ${__BUILD_VERSION}" )
message( STATUS "RESULT_VARIABLE: ${__EXECUTE_RESULT}" )
```

But he output is always

```
ERROR: 
OUTPUT_VARIABLE: 
RESULT_VARIABLE:
```

What I'm doing wrongly?

**UPDATE:** I've removed CMakeCache.txt, and it start working, but then after changes in file empty output again. Removing CMakeCache.txt didn't help

Comment: I've removed CMakeCache.txt, and it start working

Comment: What platform are you on? What is `wrong_command`? Is it a non-existing command? You showed the actual output, but what is the _expected_ output? What version of CMake are you running? Can you please provide enough detail to reproduce the problem (a [mre])?